# How to close this mobile menu after click (bootstrap5)

Tags: navigation, nav

I've been working on this website for my dad using a theme, this is the webpage:
https://alfredovazquez.me/lab/avalua.mx/

[image]

As you can see is a one page with a fixed mobile menu, I've been try with out success to close the menu after click some anchor section. I don't how to fix this, anyone can help me with a piece of code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mobileMenuTrigger = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-trigger');
const menuBlock = document.querySelector('.menu-block');
const menuOverlay = document.querySelector('.menu-overlay');
document.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
    if(e.target.closest('.mobile-menu-trigger')) {
        mobileMenuTrigger.classList.add('mobile-menu-open'); // used this class in the next if statement to check that menu is opened
    }
    if(!e.target.closest('.mobile-menu-trigger') && mobileMenuTrigger.classList.contains('mobile-menu-open')) {
        menuBlock.classList.remove('active');
        menuOverlay.classList.remove('active');
        mobileMenuTrigger.classList.remove('mobile-menu-open');
    }
});
// this piece of code is meant to be added in your custom.js file. It makes use of classes already existing in your code base except the mobile-menu-open class which is add once menu button is click and remove once a menu item is clicked
```